# Creating events in JavaScript like C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I primarily write code in C#. However, I'm working with some JavaScript. I have defined a class in JavaScript as shown here:

```
function Item(id, name) {
    this.ID = id;
    this.Name = name;

    // define event submitCompleted
    this.submit = function() {
      // When the submission is completed, fire "submitCompleted" event.
    };
}
```

My challenge is, I don't know how to create and fire custom events in JavaScript. If this was C#, I'd do the following:

```
public class Item
{
  public string ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public Item(string id, string name)
  {
    this.ID = id;
    this.Name = name;
  }

  public event EventHandler SubmitCompleted;
  public void Submit() 
  {
    // Submission logic
    SubmitCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

How do I do the equivalent in JavaScript? Thank you!

Comment: The point of events in C# is so that some container can "listen" to the event and handle it externally. What container are you intending to use to listen to this event? What object in your page is the subscriber?

Answer (score 3):

```
function Item(id, name, submitCompleted) {
    this.ID = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.submitCompleted = submitCompleted;

    // define event submitCompleted
    this.submit = function() {
        // When the submission is completed, fire "submitCompleted" event.
        // we are passing 2 arguments to the callback: id and name
        submitCompleted(id, name);
    };
}

var item = new Item(1, 'some name', function(id, name) {
    alert('id = ' + id + ', name = ' + name);
});
item.submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create custom events in javascript like this.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Event()
{
     this.eventHandlers = new Array();
}

Event.prototype.addHandler = function(eventHandler){
this.eventHandlers.push(eventHandler);
}

Event.prototype.execute = function(args){

  for(var i = 0; i < this.eventHandlers.length; i++)
  {
     this.eventHandlers[i](args);
   }
}

function showName()
{
     alert("My name is stikiflem."); 
}

function getFaveMovie(arg)
{
     alert("My favourite movie is: " + arg + "."); 
}

function test()
{
     //create event
     myHandler = new Event();

    //add handler
    myHandler.addHandler(showName);
    myHandler.addHandler(getFaveMovie);

    //raise event
    myHandler.execute("Ghost in the Shell");
}

</script>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click to create and execute events"
onClick="test()" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using jQuery then its pretty easy

```
//to register an event
$(selector).bind('customEvent', eventHandler)

// to raise an event
$(selector).trigger('customEvent')
```

If you looking for plain JS way, then

```
var newObj = function(){
 var submitHdlr = [];
 this.bind = function(handler){
  submitHdlr.push(handler);
 }
 this.submit = function(){
  // do something
  for(i in submitHdlr) 
   i(); // raise each handler
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom event definition in javascript

[Custom Javascript Events](http://the.unwashedmeme.com/blog/2004/10/04/custom-javascript-events/)